# Angularjs: post data to rails server by service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I want send data from angularjs to rails server. For this, I have an angularjs service that I use `GET`,`POST`,`DELETE`,`UPDATE` method. I can use `GET` method, but for other method I cannot use, beacause I have to sent parameter to server, but I cannot do this.

`record.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('RecordCtrl',['$scope','Session','Records', function($scope, Session, Records){
    $scope.records = Records.index();
}]);
```

`recordService.js`:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('recordService', ['ngResource']);
//angular.module('recordService', ['ngResource'])
app.factory('Records', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/record.json', {}, {
        index: { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        create: { method: 'POST' }
    });
})
    .factory('Secure', function($resource){
        return $resource('/api/record/:record_id.json', {}, {
            show: { method: 'GET' },
            update: { method: 'PUT' },
            destroy: { method: 'DELETE' }
        });
    });
```

and I get data in rails server by below code:

```
class Api::V1::RecordController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def index 
    respond_with(Record.all)
  end

  def show
    @data = Record.find(params[:id]).to_json()
    respond_with(@data)
  end

  def update 
    @data = Record.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @data.update_attributes(record_params)
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.json { render json: @data.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @data = Record.create(record_params)
    @data.save
    respond_with(@data)
  end

  def destroy
    @data = Record.find(params[:id])
    @data.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json  { head :ok }
    end
  end

  private
  def record_params
    params.require(:record).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

I don't know how can I send method from angularjs controller to rails server. I try below code, but I don't successful:

```
Records.create(function() {
        //"name" is the name of record column.
        return {name: test3};
    });
```

but I get below error in  rails server:

```
Started POST "/api/record.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-30 17:55:27 +0430
Processing by Api::V1::RecordController#create as JSON
```

1. How can I fix this problem? How can I send parameter to rails server?
2. I want send `delete` method to rails server. I know I have to send `record.id` to server, I use below type:

   ```
   //type 1
   var maskhare = { record_id: 4};
   Secure.destroy(function(){
       return maskhare.json;
   });
   //type 2
   Secure.destroy(4);
   ```

   but I get below error in server:

   Started DELETE "/api/record" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-30 19:01:21 +0430
   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/api/record"):
   I fix correct url in `recordService.js`, but I don't know why request is send to before url again. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are successfully making a request, the last line there says that a POST request was made and went to the right controller and action.

The problem is strong parameters. You need to add `name` to the filtered parameters list.

```
private
def record_params
  params.require(:record).permit(:secure, :name)
end
```

Also rails expects the parameters in the following format: `{ record: {name: 'something"} }`

**To fix your second problem**

I would try to follow [this recipe](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/backend-integration-with-ruby-on-rails/consuming-rest-apis.html)

Replace your code with this:

```
app.factory("Secure", function($resource) {
  return $resource("/api/record/:id", { id: "@id" },
    {
      'show':    { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
      'update':  { method: 'PUT' },
      'destroy': { method: 'DELETE' }
    }
  );
});
```

and then

```
Secure.destroy({id: 4});
```

Keep in mind that if you add `respond_to :json` in your controller then you can omit the `.json` in the URLs. Like so:

```
class Api::V1::RecordController < Api::V1::BaseController
  respond_to :json
  ...
end
```

Comment: The problem isn't with rails so that's a start -- Rails expect that you will call `DELETE /api/record/:id` but you are making a request that looks like this `DELETE /api/record`

Comment: I edited my answer with a fix for the AngularJS code. Let me know if that works.

Comment: You might want to update your code above so that I can see what's wrong. It's just not sending the id over.